# How is recruitment of multiunit smooth muscle cells fine tuned if they are innervated by varicosities?

Tags: neurophysiology, muscles, peripheral-nervous-system

In my physiology textbook (Silverthorn) and on wikipedia it says that:

> Multiunit smooth muscle tissues innervate individual cells; as such,
>   they allow for fine control and gradual responses, much like motor
>   unit recruitment in skeletal muscle.

However, that does not seem right to me. Although potentially each cell could be innervated, they are innervated by autonomic neurons. These neurons use the rather crude method of **varicosity innervation**. Such neurons recruit all the cells adjacent to its varicosities, not just a few. Hence, **does this not mean that there is no 'fine' control of unit recruitment of smooth muscle cells?**  Or is there an other way in which recruitment of smooth muscle cells is fine tuned?

Comment: Welcome to Bio and +1 for a good question. Could you link that wiki page?

Comment: I removed *Moreover Silverthorn states that smooth muscle cells are responding in an all or nothing fashion*, as I don't understand its relation to the question. Feel free too roll back any edits if any or all of my edits are not to your liking.